# How do you add a click to pager li element that that animates a slides opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

This is the click opacity animate function based on the pager that is clicked.

```
function clickRotate(){

 $('.control-nav-wrapper ul li').click(function() {


 var oCurPhoto = $('#slideshow div.current');
            // i gives the index of the  li clicked.
            var i = $('.control-nav-wrapper ul li').index(this);
            //sets the equivlant index to the div
            var oCurPhotoIndex = $('#slideshow div').eq(i);
```

I had to somehow remove the classes so they would all get set to clicked.

```
            $( "#slideshow div" ).each(function(){
                $(this).removeClass("previous, clicked");
            });
```

I was trying to animate the current image to 0 and set the item that was clicked to z-index of 2 with css so it would fade in.

```
            var oNxtPhoto = oCurPhotoIndex.next();

                if (oNxtPhoto.length == 0)
                    oNxtPhoto = $('#slideshow div:first');

                $(oCurPhoto).animate({opacity:0.0}, 200);

                oCurPhotoIndex.addClass('clicked').css({opacity:1.0},
                        function() {
                            oCurPhotoIndex.removeClass('current');
                 });
```

This works as a timed slideshow.

```
    function rotateImages() {
            var oCurPhoto = $('#slideshow div.current');
            var oNxtPhoto = oCurPhoto.next();
            if (oNxtPhoto.length == 0)
                oNxtPhoto = $('#slideshow div:first');

            oCurPhoto.removeClass('current').addClass('previous');
            oNxtPhoto.css({opacity:0.0}).addClass('current').animate({opacity:1.0}, 200,
                function() {
                    oCurPhoto.removeClass('previous');
                });


 #slideshow {
    position:relative;
    height:300px;
    width:537px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

#slideshow div {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:0;
    opacity:.0;
    width: 500px;
    background: green;

}

#slideshow div.current {
    z-index:3;
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

This is the css I was trying to use for the clicked item.

```
#slideshow div.clicked {
    z-index:2;
    opacity: 1.0;
}

#slideshow div.previous {
    z-index:1;
}

.control-nav-wrapper li{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please create a fiddle/plunk for it?

Comment: Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J9AF7/1/
Thank you!